# Свойство "filter:blur" перекрывает все дочерние элементы,как исправиь?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, design

Свойство "filter:blur" делает такие размытые дочерние элементы.
Как исправить данное?чтобы эфект блюр был применим именно к изображению только?
[image: blur]

Comment: закинуть картинку в отдельный элемент и его блюрить

Comment: так а если фон стоит в хедере?

Comment: вставить в хедер отдельный элемент на всю ширину и высоту с z-index и его блюрить